# Incompatible data types (text and varchar)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Sample code

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Today;
string t4 = d1.ToString("dd");
string t5 = d1.ToString("MM");
string t6 = d1.ToString("yy");
string d = t4 + "/" + t5 + "/" + t6;
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(
   "select company from app where date='"+d.ToString()+"'",connection);
MessageBox.Show(cmd1.CommandText);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
connection.Open();
da.Fill(dt);
button1.Text=dt.Rows[0]["company"].ToString();
connection.Close();
```

Error :

> The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us enough information about your schema (or what kind of database you're using), but fundamentally it's a bad idea to perform a string conversion like this. Assuming `date` really is a DATETIME column or something similar, just turn this into a *parameterized* SQL statement, and include the value as an argument. You shouldn't need to perform the conversion yourself at all.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
using (var command = new SqlCommand("select company from app where date = @p1",
                                    connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("p1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = today;
    ...
}
```

You should use parameterized SQL for pretty much *all* values. Aside from the conversion issue, it avoids SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Visual studio 2010 in build sql

Comment: Thing is i need date alone instead of getting time so i used to save it has text... even after i turn it in parameterized statement now it showing ERROR : The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: @deenadayalan: You're getting just a date using `DateTime.Today`. Given the error, it *sounds* like your `date` column is of type `text` - is that really the case? If so, you should fix your schema.

Answer (score 1):

IF app.date is a TEXT type you could one of the following:

1. Change the app.date schema, or
2. cast date as a varchar in your query: `SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select company from app where cast(date as varchar)='"+d.ToString()+"'",connection);`

Comment: SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select company from app where cast(date as varchar)='"+d.ToString()+"'",connection);                                                                                                       casting accepted ,error rectified